# Automatically connect to a PC using Dameware

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to connect from command line to a PC using the following command, but all it does is to input the fields and I have to manually click on connect.

```
dwrcc -c: -m:MachineName -u:UserName -p:Password
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try adding `-h:`

Comment: please add as solution

Comment: Done; see below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I routinely do this as part of my needs in my organization; the only difference between the command that you use and the one I use that appears relevant is that I use `-h:`, whose documentation isn't clear, but seems to implicitly use default settings for the 'host' (remote computer).

Comment: "-h: Will bypass the Dameware Mini Remote Control Host Entry settings using the default connection settings unless specified otherwise by additional command line options (used with -c)." exactly what i wanted....good documetation :(